# Android Java - create an interface which extends an existing class

Tags: java, interface, extends

I want to create my custom activity class which extends Activity,

but adds another abstracts method which inheriters must implement.

Example:

```
interface MyActivity extends Activity
{
    public void myAbstractMethod();
}
```

The IDE says :"The type Activity cannot be a superinterface of MyActivity; a superinterface must be an interface"

How can I do such thing?

Thank you.

Comment: Interfaces can only extend from other interfaces (not classes).

Comment: So there's no way I can do such thing?

Comment: @TaruStolovich, you could create an abstract class which extends `Activity` -- it's similar in function -- but since Activity contains implementation, you can't have an interface (which contains no implementation) extend it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you need `MyActivity` to be an abstract class, not an interface.  Interfaces don't inherit from classes; they can only inherit from other interfaces.

Try

```
abstract class MyActivity extends Activity
{
    public abstract void myAbstractMethod();
}
```

An abstract class with all its methods abstract behaves like an interface, so this sounds like what you need.

Comment: Thank you very much! Worked perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

You can use an abstract class instead of an interface.

Read more at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html

e.g.

```
abstract public class AbstractActivity extends Activity {
    public abstract void myAbstractMethod();
}
```

However, this does not allow you to implement both an AbstractActivity and another superclass, but it doesn't sound like you need this.

Answer (score 1):

An interface only can extends other interface, never a concrete class.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like interfaces CAN extend some classes. For example,

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService:

public **interface** ExecutorService **extends** Executor { ...


java.util.concurrent.Executor:

public **class** Executors { ...
```

but `java.util.concurrent.Executorhas` static methods only.